# KingswaySoft - JSON Source component: how to set parent key on child nodes

Tags: ssis, ado.net, kingswaysoft

I'm using the KingswaySoft JSON Source component that consumes a REST service which returns a Json with a Parent-Child structure.

I linked two ADO.Net connection to the JSON Source output, to map the parent and child nodes to the corresponding tables.

My problem is that when i map the child node, I can't find a way to retrieve and set the parent key. The mapping contains "Lookup", "_ParentKeyField" and "_RowIndex", but none of this contains the parent key.

I'm looking for suggestions to understand how to solve my intent.

Here you can see the Json structure where I highlighetd the parent id and the child node:
[image]

And here you can find the Premium ADO.NET columns for the child node (roles), with the field "profile_id" that represents the parent key:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found how to solve it:
I needed to set the Output Setting to my parent id field (id) on the Root object, as you can see on the following image (JSON Source component)

[image]

And after, on the child Ado.Net component, I mapped my parent key column to "_ParentKeyField":
[image]